# Do the four cells produced by meiosis each divide into four cells again?

Tags: meiosis

In the beginning of meiosis, there is one cell. During meiosis, 1 cell divides into 4 cells. Does each of these 4 cells divide each into 4 more cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, meiosis is not a cycle like mitosis. In mitosis, haploid or diploid cells divide to create two genetically identical cells, and this process can go on and on. On the other hand, meiosis results in 4 genetically unique daughter cells which are also haploid. If a haploid cell was to try to undergo meiosis, there would not be enough genetic material and you would end up with half-chromatids.

Comment: ...and, of course, haploid cells do mitosis too.

Comment: quite right @AlanBoyd - I should have drank my coffee this morning.

Comment: @AlanBoyd - I always taught that mitosis does not occur in haploid cells...

Comment: @siddhu99 ... perhaps I should qualify my comment: haploid **eukaryotic** cells do mitosis.

Comment: I'm only aware of this in some yeasts. Do mammalian haploid cells undergo mitosis?

Comment: Mammalian haploid cells do not undergo mitosis. In mammals at least, only meiosis during spermatogenesis result in 4 daughter cells (ironic). The meiosis in oogenesis results in a single egg and 2 polar bodies. Strangely MII in oogenesis isn't completed until fertilization.

Answer (score 1):

In species where an individual can be haploid (for example in [haplodiploidy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplodiploid)) then cells produced by meiosis do multiply by mitosis in order for the individual to grow.

From a brief scan the Wikipedia article on [ploidy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ploidy) nicely summarises the various possibilities.